# Flutter sdk not found. The error in GradleException in the build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter

I am developing a flutter application and I am having certain errors. The flutter SDK location is rightly provided but it says that Flutter SDK not found.

The error is arising from the file build.gradle inside the android folder:

```
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

I am even trying to change it but it says that "Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleExecption'".
I am also having the same error in the AndroidManifest.xml file where I am specifying the "android:icon: drawable/app_logo.png" but it says that "Cannot resolve symbol 'drawable'".

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

1 if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
cntrl+Alt+S then show settings window then search flutter you can see in under language and framework .Add flutter sdk path.
[image]

Here you verify the above path and restart the ide(Android Studio)
path :.android/local.properties
[image]

2 I am also having the same error in the AndroidManifest.xml file where I am specifying the "android:icon: drawable/app_logo.png" but it says that "Cannot resolve symbol 'drawable'".

check your path string add @withdrawable eg:  android:icon="@drawable/app_logo.png"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running Flutter Doctor and see what it gives you, if that doesn't yield anything, then try checking if the PATH for Flutter is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
GradleException()
```

to:

```
FileNotFoundException()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33303139)